# Why is an angular expression evaluating for class, but not checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because angular uses `|` for fitlers, angular expressions do not execute bitwise operators.

So now that I've written by own filter, I want to apply it for a checkbox I've mapped to an int, which is mapped to a flag on the server.

However for the following angular:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{option.numericValue}}" ng-model="value" ng-change="ctrl.onChange(value, option.numericValue)" checked="{{value | flagIsChecked: option.numericValue}}" />
```

The example output html is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="8" ng-model="value" ng-change="ctrl.onChange(value, option.numericValue)" checked="{{value | flagIsChecked: option.numericValue}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

However, if I change the `checked` attribute to a `class` attribute, the output is

```
<input type="checkbox" value="8" ng-model="value" ng-change="ctrl.onChange(value, option.numericValue)" class="checked" />
```

Why is the result of the expression displayed for `class`, but the literal of the expression displayed for `checked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because template binding works with properties and events, not attributes. That means you are trying to work with the attribute `checked` and angular is working with the properties of the DOM using `ng-checked` for example. According to the [Angular 2 documentation for **binding syntax**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax):

> **HTML Attribute vs. DOM Property**
>
> The distinction between an HTML attribute and a DOM property is crucial to understanding how Angular binding works.
>
> **Attributes are defined by HTML. Properties are defined by DOM (the Document Object Model).**
>
> - A few HTML attributes have 1:1 mapping to properties. `id` is one example.
> - Some HTML attributes don't have corresponding properties. `colspan` is one example.
> - Some DOM properties don't have corresponding attributes. `textContent` is one example.
> - Many HTML attributes appear to map to properties ... but not the way we think!
>
> That last category can be especially confusing ... until we understand this general rule:
>
> **Attributes initialize DOM properties and then they are done. Property values may change; attribute values don't.**
>
> For example, when the browser renders `<input type="text" value="Bob">`, it creates a corresponding DOM node with a `value` property initialized to "Bob".
>
> When the user enters "Sally" into the input box, the DOM element `value` property becomes "Sally". But the HTML `value` attribute remains unchanged as we discover if we ask the input element about that attribute: `input.getAttribute('value') // returns "Bob"`
>
> The HTML attribute `value` specifies the *initial value*; the DOM value property is the current `value`.
>
> The disabled attribute is another peculiar example. A button's `disabled` property is `false` by default so the button is enabled. When we add the `disabled` attribute, it's presence alone initializes the button's `disabled` property to `true` so the button is `disabled`.
>
> Adding and removing the `disabled` attribute disables and enables the button. The value of the attribute is irrelevant which is why we cannot enable a button by writing `<button disabled="false">Still Disabled</button>`.
>
> Setting the button's `disabled` property (e.g. with an Angular binding) disables or enables the button. The value of the property matters.
>
> **The HTML attribute and the DOM property are not the same thing even when they have the same name.**

So instead you should use `ng-checked`. Check the documentation for [**ng-checked**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-checked` for setting the checked attribute. see documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

> ngChecked
>   Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `ng-checked` rather than `checked`.

However, `ng-checked` and `ng-model` do not play nicely together, so this caused further issues to be resolved.

I had to move the function to evaluate the value of each member of the flag from a filter into the directive's controller:

```
    ctrl.isChecked = function(flagValue) {
        return (flagValue & scope.value) > 0;
    }
```

I kept the onChange function to update the flag whether the individual checkbox was set or unset. 
        ctrl.onChange = function (changedFlagValue) {
            //add/subtract value from parent model flags
            var isAlreadySet = (scope.value & changedFlagValue) > 0;

```
        if (isAlreadySet) {
            scope.value -= changedFlagValue;
        } else {
            scope.value += changedFlagValue;
        }
    }
```

Updating the markup to use these functions, removing the filter and using `ng-click`, not `ng-change` (since I had to remove `ng-model` which is required for `ng-change`) to trigger the function to update the flag results in:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{option.numericValue}}" ng-checked="ctrl.isChecked(option.numericValue)" ng-click="ctrl.onChange(option.numericValue)" />
```

As long at the input is wrapped by a label, clicking the label works to set the value of the checkbox and update the flag too.